# Can a function be run after the "out of memory' fatal error occurs?

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a large csv file and perform some operations on that data before saving it into the DB.  However, I get a fatal error denoting that the memory limit has been reached.  Is there any way I can run a function to save the current row number/pointer of the csv file so that the next time I run the script I can resume from that point?

Comment: My best bet would be to put the csv file into smaller chunks and parsing those individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. You should (for example) process the file line-by-line

```
$f = fopen($csv, 'rb');
while ($row = fgetcsv($f)) {
  // Do something with line
  // for example push it into a db 
}
fclose($f);
```

This way you only have in memory, what you currently need.

Comment: use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of `fgets` for more convenience